# How to setup Atom Beautify with Twig Files

Tags: templates, atom-editor

Hey everyone so I've been loving Atom and specifically the Atom beautify package which automatically cleans up indents and spacing in your markup.

The issue is i can't seem to get it to to work the way i want with Twig even though according to this thread they added support for it. https://github.com/Glavin001/atom-beautify/issues/309

I've commented on that thread asking there but I thought some of you may have found some settings that work well for twig.

It does work to indent the html around the twig pretty well but for example when you do it on something like this

```
<ul id="navigation">
{% for item in navigation %}
<li><a href="{{ item.href }}">{{ item.caption }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

it outputs this

```
<ul id="navigation">
  {% for item in navigation %}
  <li><a href="{{ item.href }}">{{ item.caption }}</a></li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

when what I'm hoping for is

```
<ul id="navigation">
  {% for item in navigation %}
    <li><a href="{{ item.href }}">{{ item.caption }}</a></li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Which i could live with the bigger issue is when you have blogs of just twig code like this

```
{% if entry.description %}
  {% set description = entry.description %}
{% else %}
  {% set description = entry.body %}
{% endif %}
```

it puts it all on one line like this

```
{% if entry.description %}{% set description = entry.description %}{% else %}{% set description = entry.body %}{% endif %}
```

Im sure theres some setting to fix this but I'm having a hard time finding out what it might be.  Anyone else have any luck getting theirs setup properly?

its worth noting that its using Pretty Diff (http://prettydiff.com) for the cleanup and it seems that it does the same with twig code

Comment: Hey Keith, I think you'd get a better answer for this on Stack Overflow. It's not really a Craft question, much more of an Atom question. I'll go ahead and migrate it!